# Chaining filters in included Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Chaining filters in Django templates seems to work normally, but when I attempt to chain django filters in included templates it doesn't.

For example in my top level template, this works:

```
<td>{{ q10a.exp|intcomma|default:"☐☐☐,☐☐☐,☐☐☐,☐☐☐.00" }}</td>
```

If `q10.exp` is `None` it renders correctly as `☐☐☐,☐☐☐,☐☐☐,☐☐☐.00`

However when I do this:

```
{% include "reports/includes/simpleSummary.html" with q=q5 %}
```

and in simpleSummary.html:

```
<td>{{ q.exp|intcomma|default:"☐☐☐,☐☐☐,☐☐☐,☐☐☐.00" }}</td>
```

However, if `q5.exp` us `None` it renders as `None`. If I remove the `|intcomma` part, it seems to work. Any idea why this happens or how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you added `{% load humanize %}` in your secondary template? I think yes as it should raise error otherwise but have you included it?

Comment: Yeah it has been included... It does throw an error without it.